# Flutter, Should we save image and video files in asset folder or phone storage directory?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am making a Flutter app that will take project pictures and videos and project information. Before sending saved data to web server, should we save those images and videos in asset folder or phone's storage directory?
I don't know which will make more secure to avoid user's action like accidentally file deletion. And also images and videos are important data like signature png files.

Comment: what `"asset folder"`? you mean the folder (`assets:`) you specify in your `pubspec.yaml`? if so, it is read only and you cannot write anything there at runtime

Comment: Thank you, @pskink. So, where can I save those pictures for not letting user see in their phone? (They can only accessible those pictures while using my app).

Comment: If you know, can you kindly tell me how to ? I don't know "the private app storage" is.

Comment: in the private app storage - more: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/persistence/reading-writing-files

Comment: Thank you. @pskink it really works!

Answer (score 0):

If you've read the [documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/persistence/reading-writing-files), there is an example there that uses the method [`getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()`](https://pub.dev/documentation/path_provider/latest/path_provider/getApplicationDocumentsDirectory.html).

> This example stores information in the documents directory.
>
> ```
> Future<String> get _localPath async {
>   final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
>
>   return directory.path;
> }
> ```

This gives path to the directory where Application can place its private files, Files only get wiped out when application itself removed.